# how to display SQL TABLE IN HTML clickling on drop down list

Tags: php, css, sql-server, html, datatable

i created a dbms in MICROSOFT SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO 2014 of the devices of a company used in different locations.each TABLE show the devices in one location. i have a html page with a drop down list! each option of which is a location that represents one table of the SQL database! please tell me how how can i link my SQL tables with the html dropdown list in such a way that when i click on a location in the dropdown list it will show the required table for that location.
also please tell me do i need to create a table similar to the sql table in the html page? or a table will appear automatically as i link the tables?
and if the above is complicated or not possible please tell me what else can i use to make it easier.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

    <HTML>

    <HEAD>
```

STATES

```
 <STYLE>

  body {
  background-image: url("pc.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat top fixed;
  background-size:1200px 600px;
   }

</STYLE>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function configureDropDownLists(ddl1,ddl2) 
 {var goa = ['GOA ASF', 'Goa LPG Plant', 'GOA LPG RO', 'Goa LPG Plant','VASCO RETAIL RO', 'VASCO TERMINAL', 'ZUARI INDIAN OILTANKING LTD'];
  var maharashtra = ['VASHI T&E', 'VASHI TERMINAL ', 'WADALA TERMINAL'];
  var rajasthan = ['AJMER LPG PLANT ','AJMER TERMINAL', 'AWA-SALAWAS ];
  var gujrat = ['AHMEDABAD NWZ LPG ', 'AHMEDABAD NWZ RETAIL', 'AHMEDABAD RETAIL RO', SILVASA LUBE PLANT','VADODARA IRD '];
  var madhyapradesh =['BAKANIA RIL', 'RATLAM BANGRUD','SAGAR IRD '];
  switch (ddl1.value)
```

{

```
  case 'Goa':
        ddl2.options.length = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < goa.length; i++) {
            createOption(ddl2, goa[i], goa[i]);
        }
        break;
    case 'Maharashtra':
        ddl2.options.length = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i < maharashtra.length; i++) {
        createOption(ddl2, maharashtra[i], maharashtra[i]);
        }
        break;
    case 'Rajasthan':
        ddl2.options.length = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < rajasthan.length; i++) {
            createOption(ddl2, rajasthan[i], rajasthan[i]);
        }
        break;
    case 'Gujrat':
        ddl2.options.length = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < gujrat.length; i++) {
            createOption(ddl2, gujrat[i], gujrat[i]);
        }
        break;
     case 'MadhyaPradesh':
        ddl2.options.length = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < madhyapradesh.length; i++) {
            createOption(ddl2, madhyapradesh[i], madhyapradesh[i]);
        }
        break;
        default:
            ddl2.options.length = 0;
        break;
}
```

}

```
function createOption(ddl, text, value) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = value;
    opt.text = text;
    ddl.options.add(opt);
}

 </script>
```

## SELECT A STATE:

Goa

Maharashtra

Rajasthan

Gujrat

MadhyaPradesh

Comment: well formatted question But application side code what can we do ? @neha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly, my thought is why do you need to keep the devices in different tables unless there are so much of data.

You can keep all the devices in one table along their location ids as below

Device table

device-id | Name     | location-id

1         | GOA ASF   | 1

2         | GOA LPG RO | 1

3         | AWA-SALAWAS | 3

Location table 
location-id | Name

1          | GOA

2          | Gujarat

3          | Rajastan

In your html do the following steps

1) On page load, get all of the locations from back end using AJAX and append it to the dropdown using javascript/jquery.

2) On change of location in the dropdown get the selected location id

3) Send a another AJAX request to get the devices of that location.

4) Now display it in the HTML once you received the response from back end.

Did you got ?